# Where can I get a reasonably small geojson file for the boundaries of Canadian provinces?

Tags: geospatial, canada

I have looked on kaggle.com and done a lot of Googling. The only thing I found was one that has 2000 vertices in the polygon for each province. That is too large to write to DynamoDb, which is what I need to do.

Comment: cross posted at GIS: https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/373388/112869

Answer (score 3):

there are many, but this one at 398 kb should probably work.

https://github.com/codeforamerica/click_that_hood/blob/master/public/data/canada.geojson

It's not "official", though. For official, you'll have to make your own geojson from [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/282508/112869).